# Google chart lines shadows

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there any way always show shadows under chart lines (like they appear after hover legend item in LineChart)?

It would be great if there's a way to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: What specific chart are you mentioning? What shadow appears in hover that you wish to be permanent?

Comment: I'm talking about Line Chart. For example if you have 2 lines with data. They both displayed at legend, right?  An if you place your mouse over one of that items in legend - line will highlight(shadow appears under whole line). I want to display such shadow under each line permanently.

Comment: I'm at [Line Chart Page](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) and I can't see what you're talking about.

Comment: See how dogs highlighted with shadow in second chart? http://imgur.com/wkauabO
It appears when I place my mouse over "Dogs" label